# Highcharts - using addSeriesAsDrilldown dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

the following code is not working, what am I doing wrong?
Loading the json_data into "options.drilldown" works but using addSeriesAsDrilldown does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

```
function getData(name) {
     var result = null;
     var scriptUrl = "data.php?name=" + name;
     $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data.drilldown;
        } 
     });
     return result;
}

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'high',
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
                if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                    data = getData(e.point.name);

                    var chart = this;

                    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
                    console.log(data);

                }
            }
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },

    series: [{}],
    drilldown: {}
};

$.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
        options.series = data.series;
        //options.drilldown = data.drilldown;
        console.log(data.drilldown);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Below is the used data, which comes from data.php:

```
    {
    "series": [
        {
            "id": "toplevel",
            "name": "Tage",
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "2016-06-08",
                    "y": 9,
                    "drilldown": "2016-06-08",
                    "title": "2016-06-08"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "drilldown": {
        "series": [
            {
                "id": "2016-06-08",
                "name": "Tarife",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "test (obscured)",
                        "y": 4,
                        "title": "test (obscured)"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "test (obscured)",
                        "y": 5,
                        "title": "test (obscured)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Using addSeriesAsDrilldown drills down but shows no Data, only a legend saying "Series2"

Comment: I think that you have problem with passing your series in addSeriesAsDrilldown method. I think that correct will be data = getData(e.point.name).series[0]; It should work in this case.

Comment: Nope, does not work, as I wrote before, console.log(data) yields the correct json data but it is not displayed as chart.

Comment: I have changed your code as I have written and it is working for me. Please compare this code: http://pastebin.com/NGrHR9L6 and this php data: http://pastebin.com/Q97YpHwV with yours.

Comment: Thanks, Grzegorz, it works now.